# How to implement pagination on a custom WP_Query Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I want to paginate my WordPress posts in a custom loop with Ajax, so when I click on load more button posts will appear.

My code:

```
<?php 
    $postsPerPage = 3;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
        'cat' => 1
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<p>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</p>
<?php
    endwhile; 
    echo '<a href="#">Load More</a>';
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

This code does not paginate. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Load More` button needs to send a `ajax` request to the server and the returned data can be added to the existent content using jQuery or plain javascript. Assuming your using jQuery this would starter code.

**Custom Ajax Handler (Client-side)**

```
<a href="#">Load More</a>
```

Change to:

```
<a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>
```

*Javascript:* - Put this at the bottom of the file.

```
//</script type="text/javascript">

    var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
    var page = 1; // What page we are on.
    var ppp = 3; // Post per page

    $("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        $.post(ajaxUrl, {
            action:"more_post_ajax",
            offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
            ppp: ppp
        }).success(function(posts){
            page++;
            $(".name_of_posts_class").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
        });

   });

//</script>
```

**Custom Ajax Handler (Server-side)**
*PHP* - Put this in the functions.php file.

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'cat' => 1,
        'offset' => $offset,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
       the_content();
    }

    exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

Comment: Whats do you need to change this line `$(".name_of_posts_class").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!` too? what's the post class

Comment: This is where your previews posts are stored e.g. "`posts-container`" (`post-1,post-2....`) now you will be adding (`post-11, post-12..`)

Comment: Simply use `paged` instead of `offset`.

Comment: Offset adds complexity if using previous buttons as well. As rkb said, best to use `$args['paged']` to establish which page to query.

Comment: What is the admin-ajax.php file referenced in the jQuery code in the first snippet. This is never referenced again

Comment: admin-ajax.php is built into wp-admin folder. You send ajax requests to this url on Wordpress sites.