# Load More Posts Ajax Button in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've had a look through the old questions and tried many of the different methods that there seems to be to do this. The closest I've got to working is this one here: [How to implement pagination on a custom WP_Query Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595391/how-to-implement-pagination-on-a-custom-wp-query-ajax)

I've tried everything and it just doesn't work. Absolutely nothing changes on the page. If you inspect the Load More Button and click it, the jQuery is making the Load More Button action as it changes from `<a id="more_posts">Load More</a>` to `<a id="more_posts" disables="disabled">Load More</a>` which even that doesn6't seem right to me anyway. It's not adding the posts, I think I'm missing something simple but for the life of me I can't work it out.

The code in my template file is:

```php
<div id="ajax-posts" class="row">
    <?php 
    $postsPerPage = 3;
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
        'cat' => 1
    ];

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile; 

    echo '<a id="more_posts">Load More</a>';
    
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
</div>
```

The code in my functions file is:

```php
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];

    header("Content-Type: text/html");
    $args = [
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'cat' => 1,
        'offset' => $offset,
    ];

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
        the_content();
    }
    exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

And my jQuery in the footer is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
        
        // What page we are on.
        var page = 5; 
        // Post per page
        var ppp = 3; 

        $("#more_posts").on("click", function() {
            // When btn is pressed.
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);

            // Disable the button, temp.
            $.post(ajaxUrl, {
                action: "more_post_ajax",
                offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
                ppp: ppp
            })
            .success(function(posts) {
                page++;
                $("#ajax-posts").append(posts);
                // CHANGE THIS!
                $("#more_posts").attr("disabled", false);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anybody see something I'm missing or able to help?

Comment: Thank You so much for the effort you've put in to help me, but i still can't get it to work. My load more button isnt clickable? do you know why that could be?

Comment: Don't know if you've seen my comment below, but If you put your ajax code in custom.js, then the code should look like this: wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery'), '', true ); wp_localize_script( 'custom_js', 'ajax_posts', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'fireproduct'), ));

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## UPDATE 24.04.2016.

I've created tutorial on my page https://madebydenis.com/ajax-load-posts-on-wordpress/ about implementing this on Twenty Sixteen theme, so feel free to check it out :)

### EDIT

I've tested this on Twenty Fifteen and it's working, so it should be working for you.

In **index.php** (assuming that you want to show the posts on the main page, but this should work even if you put it in a page template) I put:

```
    <div id="ajax-posts" class="row">
        <?php
            $postsPerPage = 3;
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                    'cat' => 8
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query($args);

            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>

         <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
         </div>

         <?php
                endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
         ?>
    </div>
    <div id="more_posts">Load More</div>
```

This will output 3 posts from category 8 (I had posts in that category, so I used it, you can use whatever you want to). You can even query the category you're in with

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
```

This will give you the category id to use in your query. You could put this in your loader (load more div), and pull with jQuery like

```
<div id="more_posts" data-category="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">Load More</div>
```

And pull the category with

```
var cat = $('#more_posts').data('category');
```

But for now, you can leave this out.

Next in **functions.php** I added

```
wp_localize_script( 'twentyfifteen-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'twentyfifteen'),
));
```

Right after the existing `wp_localize_script`. This will load WordPress own admin-ajax.php so that we can use it when we call it in our ajax call.

At the end of the functions.php file I added the function that will load your posts:

```
function more_post_ajax(){

    $ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 3;
    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;

    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'cat' => 8,
        'paged'    => $page,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    $out = '';

    if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
        $out .= '<div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
                <h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>
                <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
         </div>';

    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die($out);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

Here I've added paged key in the array, so that the loop can keep track on what page you are when you load your posts.

If you've added your category in the loader, you'd add:

```
$cat = (isset($_POST['cat'])) ? $_POST['cat'] : '';
```

And instead of 8, you'd put `$cat`. This will be in the `$_POST` array, and you'll be able to use it in ajax.

Last part is the ajax itself. In **functions.js** I put inside the `$(document).ready();` enviroment

```
var ppp = 3; // Post per page
var cat = 8;
var pageNumber = 1;


function load_posts(){
    pageNumber++;
    var str = '&cat=' + cat + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + '&action=more_post_ajax';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
        data: str,
        success: function(data){
            var $data = $(data);
            if($data.length){
                $("#ajax-posts").append($data);
                $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
            } else{
                $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);
            }
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
    return false;
}

$("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
    $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
    load_posts();
});
```

Saved it, tested it, and it works :)

Images as proof (don't mind the shoddy styling, it was done quickly). Also post content is gibberish xD

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

For 'infinite load' instead on click event on the button (just make it invisible, with `visibility: hidden;`) you can try with

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()  >= $(document).height() - 100) {
        load_posts();
    }
});
```

This should run the `load_posts()` function when you're 100px from the bottom of the page. In the case of the tutorial on my site you can add a check to see if the posts are loading (to prevent firing of the ajax twice), and you can fire it when the scroll reaches the top of the footer

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($('body').scrollTop()+$(window).height() > $('footer').offset().top){
        if(!($loader.hasClass('post_loading_loader') || $loader.hasClass('post_no_more_posts'))){
                load_posts();
        }
    }
});
```

Now the only drawback in these cases is that you could never scroll to the value of `$(document).height() - 100` or `$('footer').offset().top` for some reason. If that should happen, just increase the number where the scroll goes to.

You can easily check it by putting `console.log`s in your code and see in the inspector what they throw out

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height());
    console.log($(document).height() - 100);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()  >= $(document).height() - 100) {
        load_posts();
    }
});
```

And just adjust accordingly ;)

Hope this helps :) If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, something in the functions.php section breaks the whole site, I don't know what it could be from looking at it, but if i remove the function the site works again.

Comment: If I remover these lines from the function than the site works again so my guess is there's ann error in here: `while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
         $out .= '<div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
                <h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>
                <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
         </div>';
    }

    endwhile; 
    endif;`

Comment: Also get these errors in the console log `load_posts @ custom.js?ver=4.2.3:10
(anonymous function) @ custom.js?ver=4.2.3:32
_.event.dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=2.1.3:25
_.event.add.q.handle @ jquery.js?ver=2.1.3:24
`

Comment: I'll check this out on my local wp now, get back to you soon with updates.

Comment: Thank You so much for the effort you've put in to help me, but i still can't get it to work. My load more button isnt clickable? do you know why that could be?

Comment: Do you have any js errors on your page? Inspect the page by clicking f12

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError:ajax_posts is not definedload_posts @ custom.js?ver=4.2.3:13(anonymous function) @ custom.js?ver=4.2.3:34n.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4435n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js:4121`

Comment: Did you enqueue everything properly in the functions.php file? You need to localize script with the same handle as the js file you put your ajax call in

Comment: I think so `wp_localize_script( 'fireproduct-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'fireproduct'),
));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery'), '', true );`

Comment: If you put your ajax code in custom.js, then the code should look like this: `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery'), '', true );
wp_localize_script( 'custom_js', 'ajax_posts', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'fireproduct'), ));`

Comment: That Works! Thank you so much, One last question, If you press load more, and it only has two more fresh posts, It will then fills the gaps with posts with already had above, is there a way to stop that?

Comment: I've tested on my server and once you've loaded all the posts, there shouldn't be any more loading. Maybe I'm not understanding you completely. This works by already displaying 3 posts, and then ajax load all the rest posts (minus those 3). If this is the correct answer feel free to mark it as correct :)

Comment: I'll try and explain a bit better, I have it set to load 4 Posts, however lets say there's only 6 posts altogether, the first four load, then it loads the last two posts on click, but as well as the last two, it also reloads another 2 to make up the 4

Comment: If you copied everything like in the code, it should only load those last two. In total if you have 6 posts, and have 4 loaded, on ajax call only 2 should apperar, and that's it. Be sure that something isn't different at your end.

Comment: I just redid all your code again and still the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84151/discussion-between-dingo-d-and-addzy).

Comment: also see: [Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress - fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629203/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress-fix)

Comment: I'll fix this now ^^

Comment: @dingo_d have you any plan to do a tuto on infinite scroll with ajax ? Or have any idea on how to transform the abouve code for having infinite scroll without having to click on a button but scroll ?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem to do, I'll edit the above answer below with some code that should do the trick :)

Comment: I think it would be useful if you clarified a version of adding admin-ajax.php that was not specific to the theme. I am struggling to understand what is going on. You're hitching to twentyfifteen's functions.js that is already being enqeueued or something? I don't use twentyfifteen so what do I need to do? Just enqueue admin-ajax.php in my functions.php?

Comment: It's worth noting that if `type: "POST",` in `$.ajax` does not work using `data: str,`, either change to `type: "GET"` or use `data: { cat : cat, pageNumber : pageNumber },`

Comment: Small typo in your code, you have an extra `>` here: `<div id="more_posts" data-category="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">>Load More</div>`

Answer (score -5):

If I'm not using any category then how can I use this code? Actually, I want to use this code for custom post type.

Comment: Hey, this is not a classic forum whith an open discussion setuo. You used the "answer" field for asking another question. Next time, try and ask your question in the comments of the related answer ("add a comment").

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.