# Ajax is not working in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using ajax in WordPress and it is not working so can someone please help me out of this unwanted situation.

Here is my php code..

```
<div class="Publish">
        <h2>Published Pages</h2>
        <?php 
            $pages = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'page','post_status'=>'publish','posts_per_page'=>'-1','order'=>'ASC'));

       ?>
            <ul id="dashboard-page">
          <?php  if($pages -> have_posts()){
                while($pages -> have_posts()){
                    $pages->the_post(); ?>
                    <li id="<?php the_ID();?>" class="dashboard-item"><?php echo the_title(); ?></li>
                <?php }
            } ?>
            </ul>
        <input class="button-primary" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Click Me" />
        </div>
```

And here is the hook part.

```
    function ajax_action_stuff() {

    // doing ajax stuff
    update_option('vipin');
    die(); // stop executing script
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' ); // ajax for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' ); // ajax for not logged in users
?>
```

Here is ajaxurl code...

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head','pluginname_ajaxurl');
function pluginname_ajaxurl() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
<?php
}
```

And here is my jquery code..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
        var i = 0;var a = [];
        jQuery('#dashboard-page li').each(function(){
            a[i] = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            str = a.toString();
            i++;
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: { action: "ajax_action", pageorder: str }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any console output to provide?

Comment: I am not getting anything in my console part..

Comment: @Andrew I am hoping you got my code and what i am suppose to do with it, if you would not then i may explain further..

Comment: @Andrew, yes i am getting the following error on my console "ReferenceError: ajax_url is not defined".

Comment: I've answered the post in details about loading posts on ajax some time ago. In this answer you'll find a part about using `wp_localize_script()` to load your `admin-ajax.php` correctly in wordpress. [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress/31588401#31588401)

Comment: @dingo_d, i have done this wp_localize_script() but now the issue is that data is not being saved into wp_option table in db.

Comment: thats because you are attempting to use save_post_meta() .....

Comment: @dingo_d, i have edited the code so please have look at it again

Comment: @David, Please check the above code again, i have made the changes.

Comment: you need to make a better attempt....https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option also you need to grab the value you want to update the option with `$_POST['pageorder']`

Comment: @David thanks working now.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add $_POST['str'] in my update_option() function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any ention of ajax_url being defined. Based on your above comment this may be why you are receiving the error specified.

Comment: So, now how to it please??

Comment: Define a url to post to in your Javascript. You have plenty of options. You can also explicitly assign it, ie - 'http://example.com/api'

Comment: Is it ok?? 
jQuery.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   ajaxurl = admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
   data: { action: "ajax_action", pageorder: str }
  });