# Ajax pagination Wordpress[plugin]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I am using this plugin for wordpress:

https://sr.wordpress.org/plugins/malinky-ajax-pagination/

I need to load just 5 posts on every next and prev request

Here is my code iside template:

```
<div class=" row site-main-products">
                    <?php
                    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'posts'=>$paged);
                    $new_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-3-products post">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($new_query->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); ?></a>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></h4>
                                <h4><a class="product-name" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </h4>
                                <p><?php echo the_content() ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_query();
                    ?> 

                </div>
```

Problem with this is it just load but now show posts.

Comment: You don't need plugin for that :D [Click here and be amazed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31588401/629127) xD

Comment: It's not secure... But good point to start, thanks

Comment: Secure? In what way secure?

Comment: Well just escape everything properly and you're fine. For instance where I have `<div id="more_posts" data-category="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">>Load More</div>`, just put `<div id="more_posts" data-category="<?php echo esc_attr($cat_id); ?>">>Load More</div>, and so on.
`