# Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress - fix

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, load

On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress) from author @dingo_d I found one of the best option to load more post with ajax. but I think there is one issues. I really appreciate if author or somebody else can help me...

This part of code not work, I am not sure is this just for me or this code not work at all .. so in function.js we have this

```
var ppp = 3; // Post per page
```

and in load post this

```
var str = '&cat=' + cat + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp' + ppp + '&action=more_post_ajax';
```

in function.php we have this

```
$ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 3;
```

and everything else work just this variable 'ppp' not working .. its always use this number '3' from function.php .. and if I wrote for example number '5' in function.js its still will show 3 posts . I create exactly same files, queries and etc.. and everything work great, only this var $ppp its not work... can you please help me to see what is wrong with his code? Thanks

Comment: Woops, a typo! :O I'll fix it asap! :D

Comment: great.. and also thanks @dingo_d for great answer for Load More Posts with Ajax .. hvala puno :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :D Nema na čemu ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead

```
 '&ppp' + ppp
```

do

```
 '&ppp=' + ppp
```

Comment: I can not believe I lost two days on this.. I checked everything, but I do not see that "equal sign" missing.. :( thanks @sebastian-krysiak