# wrong position img in dom

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I used this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress) for loading posts on click( thanks very much dingo_d for answer!) and I faced with a problems.

```
$out .= '<div class="row news-row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 news-photo contact-href">
            <a href=>'.the_post_thumbnail(array(340)). '</a>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 news-text">
                <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
            </div>
        </div>';
```

img in a tag. But when I click load button img is here:

```
<img>
 <div class="row news-row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 news-photo contact-href">
            <a href=></a>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 news-text">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Why img change position?
And can I send in first request this code with variables or it`s 
impossible?

```
<a href="<?php
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
                        echo $large_image_url[0];
                        ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(340)); ?></a>
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: The problem was in incorrect data in the_post_thumbnail . Instead I use the get_the_post_thumbnail(null, array(340)) , because it`s better if you want write in functions.php