# How to load post in wordpress with ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post

This is my loop of posts:

```
<?php
$query_masonry = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
));
if ($query_masonry->have_posts()) :
    while ($query_masonry->have_posts() ) : $query_masonry->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
else :
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

at below, I have this:

```
<button id="load-more">Load more</button>
```

How I can load 3 more posts with ajax just clicking at the button "Load more"?

I've tried a lot of plugins, but unsuccessful.
Any one help me?

Comment: This question have already answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want update my code, ajax load post with fetch api:

`PHP code:`

```php
// Enqueue script.
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-load-post' );
wp_localize_script(
    'ajax-load-post',
    'ajax_load_post_data',
    array(
        'ajax_url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_load_post' ),
    )
);

// Ajax handle.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_post', 'ajax_load_post' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post', 'ajax_load_post' );
function ajax_load_post() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_load_post', 'ajax_nonce' );

    $post_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
        )
    );

    ob_start();
    if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
            $post_query->the_post();

            echo get_the_title() . '<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No posts found!';
    }
    $response['content'] = ob_get_clean();

    wp_send_json_success( $response );
}
```

`JS code:`

```js
// In js file.
document.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function() {
        var data = {
            action: 'load_post',
            ajax_nonce: ajax_load_post_data.ajax_nonce,
        };

        data = new URLSearchParams( data ).toString();

        var request = new Request(
            ajax_load_post_data.ajax_url,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: new Headers(
                    {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                )
            }
        );

        fetch( request )
            .then(
                function( res ) {
                    if ( 200 !== res.status ) {
                        console.log( 'Status Code: ' + res.status );
                        throw res;
                    }

                    return res.json();
                }
            ).then(
                function( json ) {
                    if ( ! json.success ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log( 'Json data:', json.data );
                }
            ).catch(
                function( err ) {
                    console.log( err );
                }
            ).finally(
                function() {
                    console.log( 'All Done!' );
                }
            );
    }
);
```