# Duplicate posts on AJAX call in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've attempted to setup a 'load more' button in WordPress. Simple idea, you press the button and it loads more posts using AJAX without reloading the page or needing to use pagination.

I followed a [previous article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress/31588401#31588401) on SO and have managed to get it to mostly work.

So far, I've been able to get additional posts loading fine, but for some reason, they are being duplicated. I had a look in the Networks tab and it seems each time I press the button, admin-ajax.php runs twice which I suspect is what's causing the duplication. Unfortunately, I'm not too sure what I need to change to resolve this.

It would also be really helpful to know how to get this working for custom post types as well as normal posts. On my website, I've got two post types, Standard blog posts and a custom 'Projects' post type. Each has its own page and own loop, how would I modify the above to get it to work for both? Would I need to write out the whole thing twice or maybe It's something simpler?

Any ideas guys?

Here is the HTML:

```
<section id="ajax-posts" class="layout">
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' ); ?>
</section>
<div class="load-more layout">
  <a id="more_posts" class="button"><span class="icon-plus"></span></a>
</div>
```

Here is the main loop:

```
<?php
  $postsPerPage = 1;
  $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
<div class="inner-text">
<h4 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
<h5><span class="icon-calendar"></span> <?php the_date(); ?></h5>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">Read More<span class="icon-arrow-right2"></span></a>
</div>
</article>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Here is my functions.php:

```
function wpt_theme_js() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'bigredpod-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_localize_script( 'bigredpod-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'bigredpod'),
));

}

wp_localize_script( 'bigredpod-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'bigredpod'),
));

function more_post_ajax(){

$ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 1;
$page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;

header("Content-Type: text/html");

$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'paged'    => $page,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$out = '';

if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
    $out .= 

        '<article id="post-'. get_the_ID().'" class="'. implode(' ', get_post_class()) .'">
            <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a>
            <div class="inner-text">
        <h4 class="post-title">'.get_the_title().'</h4>
        <h5><span class="icon-calendar"></span> '.get_the_date().'</h5>
        <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
        <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" class="button">Read More<span class="icon-arrow-right2"></span></a>
          </div>
        </article>';

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
die($out);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); ?>
```

Here is my JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var ppp = 1; // Post per page
var pageNumber = 1;


function load_posts(){
pageNumber++;
var str = '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + '&action=more_post_ajax';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
    data: str,
    success: function(data){
        var $data = $(data);
        if($data.length){
            $("#ajax-posts").append($data);
            $("#more_posts").addClass('posts_loading');
        } else{
            $("#more_posts").removeClass('posts_loading').addClass('no_more_posts');
        }
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
    }

});
return false;
  }

  $("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
  $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
  load_posts();
  });
});
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-load-more-posts

Answer (score 0):

You have put twice

```
wp_localize_script( 'bigredpod-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'bigredpod'),
));
```

In your `wpt_theme_js()` function. This is probably what causes the ajax to load twice.

Comment: Thanks Denis, I managed to figure it out but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out it was because I was loading my 'main.js' file twice - which contained the AJAX Code. Now I'll try to get this to work for custom posts, any help would again be much appreciated!

Comment: You basically repeat the whole process, and add `post_type` in the query. You can either do this manually, by creating separate templates, or doing this in the category page template, or you can specify the post type in a hidden field, and then fetch it in the js and then push it as `$_POST` key (a bit trickier but doable)