# ReferenceError: ajax_object is not defined when loading Wordpress post via Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I've been trying to implement the recommendation by @SagiveSEO in this thread:
[Proper way to load a single post via Ajax?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175865/proper-way-to-load-a-single-post-via-ajax)

The idea: click a button and load a post via AJAX. The idea being that you'll have a tree of buttons to allow people to navigate quickly to useful content.

Unfortunately, it fails.

In the console I get the message "ReferenceError: ajax_object is not defined" which refers to the line "$.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl..."

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```
<button class="get_project" data-postid="3300">PROJECT NAME</button>
                <div class="postcontainer"></div>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
    jQuery(function($){
    $('.get_project').click(function() {
        var postid = $(this).data('postid'); // Amended by @dingo_d
        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'my_load_ajax_content ',
            postid: postid
        }, function(data) {
            var $response   =   $(data);
            var postdata    =   $response.filter('#postdata').html();
            $('.postcontainer').html(postdata);
        });

    })
    //alert( "hello world" );
});
```

and here is the php from my functions.php file:

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {

    $pid        = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    $the_query  = new WP_Query(array('p' => $pid));

    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $data = '
            <div class="post-container">
                <div id="project-content">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">'.get_the_title().'</h1>
                    <div class="entry-content">'.get_the_content().'</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ';

        }
    }
    else {
        echo '<div id="postdata">'.__('Didnt find anything', THEME_NAME).'</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();


    echo '<div id="postdata">'.$data.'</div>';
}

// Next two lines corrected - thanks @dingo_d    
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
```

Also required in functions.php within the script enqueuing function:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myajaxpostloader',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

wp_localize_script( 'myajaxpostloader', 'ajax_object', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
```

(note that my Javascript is saved as /js/ajax.js where /js/ is a subdirectory of the Wordpress theme).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You didn't localize your ajax object. In Twenty fifteen theme you'd do it like this - in `functions.php` you'd put

```
wp_localize_script( 'twentyfifteen-script', 'ajax_object', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
));
```

Where your scripts are enqueued.

In your theme be sure to use proper handle - in stead of `'twentyfifteen-script'` put the one where your ajax code is in. So if your ajax JavaScript is located in a file called `custom.js`, and you've enqueued that script with the handle `custom_js`, then you'd put

```
wp_localize_script( 'custom_js', 'ajax_object', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
));
```

After you've enqueued that script. All in all in your `functions.php` you'd put something like this:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_theme_setup');

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_theme_setup' ) ){
    function mytheme_theme_setup(){
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts');
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_scripts' ) ){
    function mytheme_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'custom_js', 'ajax_object', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Or at the very least look for such code and just place the localization there :)

Comment: Thanks, @dingo_d - I did in fact enqueue and localize the script, but I didn't really understand the localize_script code, so this is a big help.

However, my script now returns 0 as the HTML result.

Any idea why?

Comment: Be sure that `var postid = $(this).attr('data-postid');` returns correct post id. I'd use `var postid = $(this).data('postid');` instead.

Comment: Thanks, @dingo_d, but that's not the problem - there's something more fundamental.

I tried changing the function to this...

function my_load_ajax_content () {
    echo 'hello world';
}

...but it still returns 0 every time. Any idea what's wrong?!

Comment: Your actions should be: `add_action ( 'wp_ajax_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' ); add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );`

Comment: That's a big help, thanks. I have amended the original code to reflect your help. I now realise my fundamental problem is that I don't understand the Javascript so I need to do some studying. But your solution works, so thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I have a tutorial, and there is a question here that I answered about using AJAX, feel free to check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress/31588401#31588401) :)

Comment: Be sure use wp_enqueue_script function before wp_localize_script