# How to add custom html to ajax load more (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have added a "load more" button with ajax by following this posting...

[Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)

However, I need to add in some custom HTML for the content to sit in. I tried making a template and adding that into my ajax call but I couldn't get it working as the entire template would post 5 times.(I'm incrementing posts by 5). My question is, how do you structure the HTML in PHP for the ajax object?

My ajax function is here (in `functions.php`):

```
function more_post_ajax(){

$ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 5;
$page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;

header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    $postcounter = 1;
    $mediumcounter = 0;
    $smallcounter = 0;

$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
   // 'cat' => 8,
    'paged'    => $page,

);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$out = '';

if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
    /******I NEED TO CHANGE THE BELOW*******/
     $out .= '<div class="parent">
            <h1>play ball '.get_the_title().'</h1>
            <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>

     </div>';


endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
die($out);
```

The template file I was trying to load up looks like this...

```
<?php

    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 5
    );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    $postcounter = 1;
    $mediumcounter = 0;
    $smallcounter = 0;

    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );


    if($postcounter == 1 ){

            echo '<div class="parent">';
            echo '<div class="single postwrapper child-2 postwrapper'.$postcounter.' mediumpost gray">';
    }
    else if($postcounter == 2 ){

        echo '<div class="multi postwrapper child-2 ">';
        echo '<div class="parent">';    


    }else{
        $smallcounter = $smallcounter + 1;
        if(in_array($smallcounter, array(1,2))){
            $postcolor = 'blue';
        }else{
            $postcolor = 'gray';
        }
    }
    echo '<div class="postwrapper child-2 postwrapper'.$postcounter.' smallpost '. $postcolor .'">';

      get_template_part( 'homenew', get_post_format() );

      echo '</div>';  

       if($postcounter == 1 || $postcounter == 5 ){
           echo '</div>';
           if($postcounter == 5){
             echo '</div>';  
           }
       }
        $postcounter = $postcounter + 1;

    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Would I have to write the template file out in the ajax function? Or just send post info to the javascript and append custom js with jquery?