# Ajax not working in Wordpress (xampp)

Tags: ajax, wordpress, xampp

I am learning to use Ajax in wordpress (on Xampp)

Jquery file (jquery_test.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "http://www.wordpress2.com/demo_test.txt", 
success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
      }});
   });
});
```

Functions.php:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {

 $myfile = get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery_test.js';

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-great-script', $myfile, array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0', true );
 }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

My json file is called "demo_test.txt"

The webpage name is "test" (a button  on the page fires the ajax.)

When I click the button on page "test", and view the console, the ajax request is made to

www.wordpress2.com/test/demo_test.txt

BUT the file demo_test.txt does not reside there..... so it is not found.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)

Comment: There are so much more other posts on this subject on SO. Please search before posting...