# Triggering Flexslider after WordPress AJAX post load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am loading posts via Ajax, and each post has a Flexslider(2) carousel, which isn't loading. I believe it may have to do with the timing of the post - the Flexslider script is running before the post loads, so it isn't triggered. I've tried a callback function and binding the Flexslider to the success call but can't get it to work. Is there an ideal way to do this?

(Flexslider runs fine on the page outside of the Ajax content.)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $(".events_link").click(function () {
            var eventname = $(this).attr('id');
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: "all_event",
                    eventname: eventname
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(".events-thumbs").html(response);
                }
            });

        });

        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: "false",
            animationLoop: true,
            itemWidth: 192,
            itemMargin: 9,
            controlNav: true,
            directionNav: false
        });

    });
```

Adding flexslider to the success callback WORKED!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $(".events_link").click(function () {
            var eventname = $(this).attr('id');
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: "all_event",
                    eventname: eventname
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(".events-thumbs").html(response);
                    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                        animation: "slide",
                        slideshow: "false",
                        animationLoop: true,
                        itemWidth: 192,
                        itemMargin: 9,
                        controlNav: true,
                        directionNav: false
                    });
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the flexslider function in your ajax success function? Maybe you could call it after appending the html to your `.event-thumbs`.

Comment: You shouldn't put JavaScript inside php. Put it in a file that you'll enqueue properly. You can see the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress/31588401#31588401)

Comment: @Huelfe I did try that, and it had no effect; I've updated code in post with my attempt

Comment: @dingo_d thank you, you are right. It will be enqueued once I have the Flexslider working! :)

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? And have you checked the HTML to see if it is perhaps there but just not showing?

Comment: @Und3rTow No errors. And it IS there and not showing - that is the default of the Flexslider CSS (the function removes the display:none). I have this same div and content replicated on another non-Ajax page, just for troubleshooting, and it is displaying/functioning as expected.

Comment: I figured out the issue! Adding to the success call actually did work - I was in the wrong Ajax function entirely. I forgot I had nested Ajax queries and was in the wrong one. Case closed, fixed! Thank you for your help. @Huelfe had the right answer

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add the flexslider function into the Ajax success call as another function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".events_link").click(function () {
        var eventname = $(this).attr('id');
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "all_event",
                eventname: eventname
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(".events-thumbs").html(response);
                $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    slideshow: "false",
                    animationLoop: true,
                    itemWidth: 192,
                    itemMargin: 9,
                    controlNav: true,
                    directionNav: false
                });
            }
        });

    });

});
```