# Wordpress and Ajax form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm totally lost here. Can anyone check what is going wrong with the form I'm trying to create here? It should send data with Ajax in WP custom theme without storying anything in the DB.

The console gives me an error that "firstname is not defined", line 67 of jQuery - `data:{name:firstname, email:email, message:comment,action:'validate_form'}` , but truly, I believe it will be more than that.

```
<form class="form">
      <div class="form__item form__item_no-margin">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="What's your name?*" class="firstname" required>
        <p class="error-message">This is field is required!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="What's your email address?*" class="email" required>
        <p class="error-message">This is field is required!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
        <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Please, leave a message!*" class="textarea" required></textarea>
        <p class="error-message">This is field is required!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-btn">
        <p class="error-message error-message_main val-error">All the required fields have to be filled out.</p>
        <p class="success-message val-success">Thanks. I'll contact you ASAP!</p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

And some jQuery:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".submit-btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = jQuery(".firstname").val();
  var email = jQuery(".email").val();
  var message = jQuery(".textarea").val();
  var ajaxUrl = "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";

if(name === "" || email === "" || message === "") {
  jQuery(".val-error, .error-message").show();
  jQuery("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery(".val-error").offset().top
}, 700)
}
else {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl, 
    method:"POST",
    data:{name:firstname, email:email, message:comment,action:'validate_form'},
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
      jQuery(".val-success").show(fast);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

PHP in the functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myaction', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'my_action_callback');


function my_action_callback(){
 $name= trim($_POST["firstname"]);
 $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
 $comment = trim($_POST["comment"]);

 $page_title = "New form submission";
 $message = "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nMessage: $comment";
 mail('some@email.com', $page_title, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: some@email.com" );
wp_die();
```

}

UPDATE

Attached is the fresh version in codepen. PHP is down below.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVWaJY

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myaction', 'validate_form_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'validate_form_callback');


function validate_form_callback(){
$name= trim($_POST["firstname"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$comment = trim($_POST["comment"]);

$page_title = "New form submission";
$message = "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nMessage: $comment";
mail('some@email.com', $page_title, $message, "Content-type: 
text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: some@email.com" );
wp_die();
```

}

Comment: There are literally thousands of tutorials on ajax in WordPress. I even did it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress/31588401#31588401. First of all, never call `ajaxurl` that way. Localize it. Second, where is your variable `firstname` in the `data` object? And lastly, why aren't you using `$` instead of pasting everywhere `jQuery`. Just put it in your ` jQuery(document).ready(function($){`. Is your jquery in a separate script, dependent on `jQuery`?

Comment: Hey bud. Thanks for your reply. The thing is that I'm not a tech guy. It took me literally 3 days to get the code I submitted above to work at least with validation. Now I'm at the point when I don't know where I should head. That's why I'm asking for help. Codex documentation for WP won't help me at all.

Comment: @zametsv - what is the actual problem now? (CodePen just indicates there are no jQuery present and is therefore not working)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld The problem now is that even thought I have data in form fields, it still validates it, if there was nothing, with error message. And, it doesn't send any data to the specified email in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Think it may just be this typo:
`var name = jQuery(".firstname").val();`
The variable passed to data
      `name:firstname,`
Let me know if that solves your problem. If not, I will look again. : )

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with the code you've posted, as you've already identified, is the error in the console.

You're creating a variable `name` (ln 4) and then trying to reference it as `firstname` (ln 19). You're doing the same thing in the PHP callback. The object in the AJAX request sets the value as `name` yet you're trying to retrieve it with `firstname`.

The same problem applies to `comment`. The best approach would be to pick a label and use it consistently. Mixing `comment` and `message` will only lead to confusion.

The second issue is with the action. Your JS code sets the action as `validate_form` but your callback fires on `myaction`.

JS Updates:

```
. . .

var firstname = jQuery( ".firstname" ).val();
var email = jQuery(".email").val();
var comment = jQuery(".textarea").val();

. . .

method:"POST",
data: {
    firstname: firstname, 
    email: email,
    comment: comment,
    action: 'validate_form'
},
```

PHP Updates:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_validate_form', 'validate_form_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_form', 'validate_form_callback' );

function validate_form_callback() {
```

Comment: Nathan, thanks. So I added all those changes you suggested, and now, this error in the console is gone, but the form won't send the data anyway, plus, even though all the fields are filled out, when I press submit button, it shows a validation error, if they weren't filled out.

Comment: @zametsv - please update what you've done in your original question, so we can help you further :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I updated the code above. Have a look please.

Comment: You did update the validation line right? `if(name === "" || email === "" || message === "") {` should be `if ( firstname ...  comment ....`

Answer (score 0):

Hello your data parameter need to be instead like this, you have inverted the way is suppose to be writting, your variable should be on the right side and the name you are going to use to call it in the php code should be in the left side:
`data:{firstname:name, email:email, comment:message, action:'validate_form'},`

remember that your variable your are passing are:
`var name = jQuery(".firstname").val(); var email = jQuery(".email").val(); var message = jQuery(".textarea").val();`

and in your php you are going to call like this:

`$name= trim($_POST["firstname"]); $email = trim($_POST["email"]); $comment = trim($_POST["comment"]);`