# Using Ajax in Wordpress Custom Theme

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, blogs

I made a custom blog theme for Wordpress.
I am trying to real-time load more posts, on scroll with Ajax.

I tried to understand through various tutorials how to implement Ajax in my custom WP theme but I completely failed.

Could you please explain in simple words the process?

Comment: show us your failed code, so that we can help!

Comment: It is sadly not something that can be explained in simple words. I think this person explains it pretty well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588401/8085668. If you are still struggling you could give this plugin a try https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/. (I haven't personally tried it)

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/ easy to configure. And can edit template from admin without going in code .