# I want to add load more button for particular custom post type in wordPress. Post display when click on the button

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is the code of PHP and file save as an aboutus.php. Now please tell me that I want to add load more button for particular custom post type in WordPress. Post display when clicking on the button

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h2>News & Announcements</h2>
    </div>

     <?php 
            $args = array('post_type' => 'news','showposts'=>6, 'order'=>'ASC');
            $query = new wp_query ($args);
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post() ;
            $img = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($result->ID));
          ?>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 news">

      <figure><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>"></figure>

      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

      <?php the_content(); ?>

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

   </div>

   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h4>
        <a id="toggle">Show more</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add an event listeren with javascript to listen to the 'click' event on the `#toggle` button, make an ajax request to fetch the next post(s) and append the post(s) to the post on success.

This helped me in the beginning with making ajax requests: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/