# Load More Posts with AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am staring myself blind at some code I can't get to work.

The environment is WordPress and I am trying to get a "Load more" button to load more posts within a listing without page reloading. This is implemented using AJAX.

I have four posts and I am displaying three post per page. When the "Load more" button is clicked, the post list wont add the fourth and last post below.

The following page template is where the post list is displayed:

```
<div class="woocommerce columns-3">
    <ul class="products columns-3">

        <?php 

        $query_params = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'post_type'    => 'post'
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($query_params); 



        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <li class="product post-item">
                <span class="post-image">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php 
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail()) 
                            {
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                            }
                        ?>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <span class="post-category"><?php the_category(', ');?></span>
            </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </ul>

</div>

<nav>
    <?php
        if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
        {
            echo '<div class="post_loadmore">More posts</div>'; 
        }
    ?>
</nav>
```

My functions.php contains following code:

```
<?php

    function my_load_more_scripts() 
    {

        global $wp_query; 

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'post_loadmore_params', array(
            'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
            'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), 
            'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
            'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_more_scripts' );

    function post_loadmore_ajax_handler()
    {
        $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
        $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; 
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

        query_posts( $args );

        if( have_posts() ) :

            while( have_posts() ): the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

        endif;
        die;
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'post_loadmore_ajax_handler');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'post_loadmore_ajax_handler');

?>
```

The final code is the AJAX, that controls the load more functionality:

```
 jQuery(function($){
    $('.post_loadmore').click(function(){

        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': post_loadmore_params.posts, 
            'page' : post_loadmore_params.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : post_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, 
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); 
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); 
                    post_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( post_loadmore_params.current_page == post_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                        button.remove(); 

                } else {
                    button.remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Link to page is here - https://www.uvjagtpro.dk/arkiv/

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Please have a look :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Try adding an `else` statement to your `if( have_posts() ) :` condition and have it echo something like `echo "No posts found";` to check if your query is actually working or not.

Comment: Thank you, cabrerahector

It appears, that the query does not work. I am trying to echo out text within the if-statement and the while-loop and nothing appears. 

Any idea why ?