# Show more post every call with wp_query Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I use this argument to show the number of post in the wp_query

```
posts_per_page
```

But, every time that I call the function of wp_query, I need to show, for example:

in the first call: the first 5 post
in the second call: the next 5 post
in the third call: the next 5 post

at the end, there would be 15 post in total

Like a "see more" button

How can I do that with the arguments in the wp_query ?

Thanks

Comment: 'paged' specifies the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is couple of plugin for same :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/

You can do this with custom way as well.

You can take the reference from here.

[Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)

https://madebydenis.com/ajax-load-posts-on-wordpress/