# Using AJAX to load more products WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using AJAX to load more products on a WooCommerce archive. I have used AJAX to "Load More" once before on [this page](https://www.sensorcity.co.uk/event/). I have used the same code for the most part, just altered the `WP_Query` arguments to suit my needs. I can't understand why my code doesn't work.

**JS**

```
/**
 * AJAX Load (Lazy Load) events
 */

$('#load-more').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ajax_next_posts()
    $('body').addClass('ajaxLoading');
});

var ajaxLock = false; // ajaxLock is just a flag to prevent double clicks and spamming

if( !ajaxLock ) {

function ajax_next_posts() {

    ajaxLock = true;

    // How many posts there's total
    var totalPosts = parseInt( jQuery( '#found-posts' ).text() );

    // How many have been loaded
    var postOffset = jQuery( 'li.product' ).length

    // How many do you want to load in single patch
    var postsPerPage = 1;

    // Ajax call itself
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: leafshop.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_next_posts',
            post_offset: postOffset,
            posts_per_page: postsPerPage,
            product_cat: cat_id
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done( function( response ) { // Ajax call is successful
        // console.log( response );

        // Add new posts
        jQuery( '.product-grid' ).append( response[0] );

        // Log SQL query
        jQuery( '#query > pre' ).text( response[2] );

        // Update the count of total posts
        // jQuery( '#found-posts' ).text( response[1] );

        ajaxLock = false;

        console.log( 'Success' );

        $('body').removeClass('ajaxLoading');

        // How many posts there's total
        var totalPosts = parseInt( jQuery( '#found-posts' ).text() );
        console.log( "Total Posts: " + totalPosts );

        // How many have been loaded
        var postOffset = jQuery( 'li.product' ).length
            console.log( "Posts currently showing: " + postOffset );

        // Hide button if all posts are loaded
        if( totalPosts < postOffset + ( 1 * postsPerPage ) ) {
            jQuery( '#load-more' ).fadeOut();
        }

    })
    // .fail( function() {
    .fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // Ajax call is not successful, still remove lock in order to try again

        ajaxLock = false;

        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);

        console.log( 'Failed' );

    });
}
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

/**
 * Load next 12 products using AJAX
 */
function ajax_next_posts() {
    global $wpdb;
    // Build query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>  'product'
    );
// Get offset
if( !empty( $_POST['post_offset'] ) ) {

    $offset = $_POST['post_offset'];
    $args['offset'] = $offset;

    // Also have to set posts_per_page, otherwise offset is ignored
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 12;
}

// Get posts per page
if( !empty( $_POST['posts_per_page'] ) ) {
    // Also have to set posts_per_page, otherwise offset is ignored
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['posts_per_page'];
}

// Set tax query if on cat page
if( !empty( $_POST['product_cat'] ) ){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
                            'taxonomy'          =>  'product_cat',
                            'terms'             =>  array( (int)$_POST['product_cat'] ),
                            'field'             =>  'id',
                            'operator'          =>  'IN',
                            'include_children'  =>  1
                        );
}

$count_results = '0';

$ajax_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Results found
if ( $ajax_query->have_posts() ) {
    $count_results = $ajax_query->found_posts;

    // Start "saving" results' HTML
    $results_html = '';
    ob_start();

    while( $ajax_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $ajax_query->the_post();
        echo wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }

    // "Save" results' HTML as variable
    $results_html = ob_get_clean();
}

// Build ajax response
$response = array();

// 1. value is HTML of new posts and 2. is total count of posts
global $wpdb;
array_push ( $response, $results_html, $count_results, $wpdb->last_query );
echo json_encode( $response );

// Always use die() in the end of ajax functions
die();  
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');
```

The AJAX call runs successfully but doesn't return what I'd expect it to. I'd expect it to return the next product from the current category, instead it returns a product from a different category. The development site is accessible on http://leaf.kalodigital.co.uk and I have been using the ["Black Tea"](http://leaf.kalodigital.co.uk/product-category/loose-leaf-tea/black-tea/) page in my testing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588401/629127 ? Just modify the query to query products, not regular posts. The logic is basically the same. Also, no need to use `$wpdb`, especially calling the `global $wpdb` twice ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)

Comment: @dingo_d realised that was in there twice after posting. I put it in so that I can return $wpdb->last_query with the AJAX response to debug the query.

Comment: @dingo_d I’ve used most of the reference question when building my solution. My issue is, the wrong posts are returned. It’s as though the query is ignoring the tax query section.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how WooCommerce handles the categories. That could be why it's not working. Also be careful to check category slugs vs names. Try modifying that part and see what changes. Also query monitor can help to see what query is executed :)

Comment: @dingo_d Looks like the cause of my issue might be because I'm using WP_Query instead of WC_Product_Query. I'll post an answer when I get my new code working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Method

After some further research, I found that WooCommerce contains a class names `WC_Poduct_Query`. Following their documentation, found here, I rebuilt my query. This *was* working in the sense that it was querying for the correct products and returns the ones I'd expect it to as an array of `WC_Product_Variable` Objects. I proceeded to, within a `foreach` loop, use `setup_postdata( $post );` to set the product Objects up so that I could use the `wc_get_template_parts();` function to call the `content-product.php` template to format the output of the data. I found that this didn't work, although I couldn't figure to why this was the case, using `setup-postdata();` was causing the object to turn into `[{id:0,filter:raw},{id:0,filter:raw}]`. I imagine this would be related to the `WC_Product_Variable` Objects not matching the expect format that `setup_postdata();` usually expects from a `WP_Post` Object.

Nonetheless, I reverted to using `WP_Query` for my query, rebuilt the query script from scratch and, would you believe it, everything worked as expected to. Below is my working code to AJAX load the next "bunch" of products on **any** WooCommerce Archive page, at the click of a button.

### Code

**JS**

```
/**
 * AJAX Load (Lazy Load) events
 */

 //--   Settings

// How many do you want to load each button click?
var postsPerPage = 12;

//--    /Settings

// How many posts there's total
var totalPosts = parseInt( jQuery( '#found-posts' ).text() );

// if( totalPosts == postOffset ) {
//  jQuery( '#load-more' ).fadeOut();
// }

$('#load-more').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get current category
    var cat_id  =   $(this).data('product-category');


ajax_next_posts( cat_id );
    $('body').addClass('ajaxLoading');
});

var ajaxLock = false; // ajaxLock is just a flag to prevent double clicks and spamming

if( !ajaxLock ) {

    function ajax_next_posts( cat_id ) {

        ajaxLock = true;

        // How many have been loaded
        var postOffset = jQuery( 'li.product' ).length;

        // Ajax call itself
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: leafshop.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_next_posts',
                post_offset: postOffset,
                posts_per_page: postsPerPage,
                product_cat: cat_id
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done( function( response ) { // Ajax call is successful

            // Add new posts
            jQuery( '.product-grid' ).append( response[0] );

            // Update Post Offset
            var postOffset = jQuery( 'li.product' ).length;

            ajaxLock = false;

            console.log( 'Success' );

            $('body').removeClass('ajaxLoading');

            // How many posts there's total
            console.log( "Total Posts: " + totalPosts );

            // How many have been loaded
            var postOffset = jQuery( 'li.product' ).length
            console.log( "Posts on Page: " + postOffset );

            // Hide button if all posts are loaded
            if( ( totalPosts - postOffset ) <= 0 ) {
                jQuery( '#load-more' ).fadeOut();
            }

        })
        // .fail( function() {
        .fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // Ajax call is not successful, still remove lock in order to try again

            ajaxLock = false;

            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);

            console.log( 'Failed' );

        });
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

/**
 * Load next 12 products using AJAX
 */
function ajax_next_posts() {
global $product;
// Build Query
    $args = array(
            'post_type'             =>  'product',
            'posts_per_page'        =>  (int)$_POST['posts_per_page'],
            'orderby'               =>  'title',
            'order'                 =>  'ASC',
            'offset'                =>  (int)$_POST['post_offset'],
        );

if( !empty( $_POST['product_cat'] ) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
                            'relation'  => 'AND',
                                array (
                                    'taxonomy'  =>  'product_cat',
                                    'field' =>  'slug',
                                    'terms' => $_POST['product_cat'],
                                    'operator'  =>  'IN'
                                ),
                        );
}

$count_results = '0';

$ajax_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Results found
if( $ajax_query->have_posts() ){

    // Start "saving" results' HTML
    $results_html = '';
    ob_start();

    while( $ajax_query->have_posts() ) {

        $ajax_query->the_post();
        echo wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // "Save" results' HTML as variable
    $results_html = ob_get_clean();

} else {

    // Start "saving" results' HTML
    $results_html = '';
    ob_start();

    echo "none found!";

    // "Save" results' HTML as variable
    $results_html = ob_get_clean();

}

// Build ajax response
$response = array();

// 1. value is HTML of new posts and 2. is total count of posts
array_push ( $response, $results_html );
echo json_encode( $response );

// Always use die() in the end of ajax functions
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_next_posts', 'ajax_next_posts');
```

### Use Cases

By refactoring the supplied AJAX code, it would be possible to turn this solution into an "infinite scrolling" system as opposed to a "Load More" button solution. Please feel free to reuse this code where it may see fit!