# How can display 5 latest posts first, then load more ajax the rest of posts in index.php file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a beginner Wordpress. In `index.php` , I want to display 5 latest posts first, and then I will use load more ajax to show the rest of posts when I scroll down (Each scroll will show 4 posts.). This is `index.php` :

```
//some code here
 <div class="main-content">
        <?php
        $paged = 1;
        if (get_query_var('paged')) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        }
        $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
        // the query
        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'showposts' => 5,
                'paged' => $paged
            )
        );
        ?>

        <?php if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) :
            while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) :
                $wpb_all_query->the_post();
                get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_type());
            endwhile;
            ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
//some code here
```

Here is load more ajax function :

```
function loadmore_ajax_handler()
{
    // prepare our arguments for the query
    $args = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['query'] ), true);
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 4;

    query_posts( $args );

    if(have_posts()) :
        while(have_posts()): the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type());
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
    endif;
    die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'loadmore_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'loadmore_ajax_handler');
```

But when i set `posts_per_page = 4` , it had a problem :  I showed 5 latest posts, but when load more ajax, it show fifth post again. I want it to show start from the sixth post and each call ajax time, it will show 4 posts. How can I fix it. Please help me , Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load More Posts Ajax Button in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)

Comment: I think it's not. I need to show 5 latest posts first WITHOUT ajax. Then, I use ajax to load the rest of posts (load 4 posts in each time call ajax). I think the bottom line is in setting $wp_query how to reasonable