# how to add load more button in custom blog post loops in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add a load more posts button in my blog page template (template-parts/blog.php) in this code. I created a post loop but now i need serious help, i tried whole internet but couldnt get through.. i dont know what to do to make load button work. how to add load more button in custom blog post loops ? i followed many tutorials but none of them work or may be i am doing it wrong but please help

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Blog
 * The template for displaying blog list.
 *
 */


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header();

?>




<div class="main-blog">

        <div class="blog-filter">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="inner-blog">
                    <div class="blog-heading">
                        <h2 id="SectionName" >Blog</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    <div class="portfolio section">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="filters">
          <ul class="toolbar">
              
            <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
              <?php
                  $argss = array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'category',
                      'hide_empty' => 0,
                      'include' => array( 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
                  );
                  $termss= get_terms($argss);
                  $counts = 1;
                  foreach($termss as $terms){
                  //print_r($terms);
                ?>
            <li data-filter=".<?php echo $terms->slug; ?>"><div class="cat-img"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($terms->term_id); ?>" /></div> <?php echo $terms->name; ?></li>
              <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="filters-content">
          <div id="portfolio" >
              <div >
              <?php
              $args = array(  
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                  'posts_per_page' => 15,
                  'taxonomy' => 'category',
                  'include' => array( 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23),
              );

              $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

              while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
              $categories = get_the_category();
              $cats = "";
              foreach($categories as $category){
                  $cats .= $category->slug." ";
              }
              ?>
            <div class="tile scale-anm all <?php echo $cats; //echo get_the_category(); ?>">
              <div class="item ">
                  <div class="img-sec">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cnt-sec">
                      <div class="cat">
                          <?php 
                          $category_object = get_the_category($loop->ID);
                          $category_name = $category_object[1]->name;
                          ?>
                          <p><?php the_category(' '); ?></p>
                      </div>
                      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                      <p>
                          <?php the_excerpt(70);  ?>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <?php
                endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
         ?>
    </div></div>
    <div id="more_posts">Load More</div>
               
            
              
          </div>
            
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="1916"]' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load More Posts Ajax Button in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)

Comment: i tried this too but when i click on load more button its doing nothing. so i revert it back to above code. i am not getting it how to make it done

Comment: Please edit the code example to include only the relevant parts of code, to make your question more readable. And include more information (with code examples) of the approaches you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You do this using an AJAX request. So your question is missing two parts: the server-side PHP script and the client-side JS script.

Server-side:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , function () {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax_load_more' , 'load_more.js' , array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_load_more' , 'AjaxLoad' , array( 'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) , ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_load_more' );
} );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getmoreposts', array( __CLASS__ , 'fetch_data' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getmoreposts', array( __CLASS__ , 'fetch_data' ) );

function fetch_data () {
    if ( !$_POST[ 'paged' ] ) { 
        $json = array( 'status' => 'error' , 'message' => 'no pagination found' ); 
    } else {
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' , 'post_status' => 'publish' , 'posts_per_page' => 9 , 'paged' => (int)$_POST[ 'paged' ] ) );
        if ( $query -> found_posts > 0 ) {
            $json = array( 'status' => 'ok' , 'message' => 'all ok' , 'posts' => $query -> posts );
        } else{
            $json = array( 'status' => 'error' , 'message' => 'no posts found' );
        }
    }
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
    echo json_encode( $json );
    exit;
}
```

Explained: In wp_ajax_nopriv_ and wp_ajax_ we register an ajax action getmoreposts. If the client calls this action, the server will respond with the function fetch_my_data. The $_POST variable tells the server which page to load.
The request is handled in the js file.

```
;( function ( window , document , $ ) {
    var paged = 1;

    jQuery( document ).on( 'click' , '#more_posts' , () => {
        paged++;
        jQuery.ajax( {
            type : 'POST' ,
            url : AjaxLoad.ajaxUrl,
            data : { action : 'getmoreposts' , paged : paged } , 
            success : ( data , textStatus , XMLHttpRequest ) => { 
                data.posts.forEach( ( post , index ) => { /*do something*/ } );
            } ,
            error : ( XMLHttpRequest , textStatus , errorThrown ) => { console.log( errorThrown ); }
        } );
    } );
} )( window , document , jQuery );
```

Specifically, the recieved data will be handled by the function defined in the success attribute of the ajax request.

Concluding, the user clicks the button, the client sends a request with the action "getmoreposts" to the server via ajax (no page reload!), the server responds with the posts and the client appends new items to the post list. The user is happy.