# Issue implementing infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have an issue implementing infinite scrolling. I have seen some questions similar to mine but didn't find a solution to mine. 
I also tried to implement the solution in this question: [How to implement pagination on a custom WP_Query Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595391/how-to-implement-pagination-on-a-custom-wp-query-ajax)

Mainpage.php:

```
<div class="large-12 columns ">
    <ul class="products">
    <?php
        $postsPerPage = 4;
        // args
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
            'product_cat' => 'seating',
        );
        // get results
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // The Loop
    ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php
        endwhile; 
        echo '<a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>';
    ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    </ul><!--/.products-->
</div>
```

at the end of same page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
var page = 1; // What page we are on.
var ppp = 4; // Post per page

$("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
    $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
    $.post(ajaxUrl, {
        action:"more_post_ajax",
        offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
        ppp: ppp
    }).success(function(posts){
        page++;
        $(".name_of_posts_class").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO] where you questions can be answers, but "i cant seem to put mine to work" is not a question. What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? What else have you tried?

Comment: Question rewording and code formatting

Comment: What is it exactly that doesn't work as you wish?