# AJAX Load More on Custom Post Grid

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I cant get this to work. I am trying to create a custom post type grid with ajax load more button to show 6 mosts per page in the grid. I can get the posts to show but the Load More button just scrolls to the top of the page like a normal anchor link.

My theme code:

```
    <div class="tabgrid">
          
          <?php 
    $postsPerPage = 6;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'dslc_projects',
        'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
        'offset' => $offset
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?><div class="project-grid-item">

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                <p>View project...</p> </a>
           </div><?php
    endwhile; ?>
           
    <?php echo '<div id="more_posts">Load More</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
           </div>
        </div>
```

My PHP:

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'offset' => $offset
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
       the_content();
    }

    exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

My JS:

```
var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
    var page = 1; // What page we are on.
    var ppp = 6; // Post per page

    $("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        $.post(ajaxUrl, {
            action:"more_post_ajax",
            offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
            ppp: ppp
        }).success(function(posts){
            page++;
            $(".tabgrid").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
        });

   });
```

can anyone see what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor is just a normal anchor and `href="#"` means scroll to top. Your JS code is trying to add a handler to and element with the id "#more_posts" but your anchor doesn't have an id.

Try replacing your anchor with `<div id="more_posts">Load More</div>`

Comment: I cant believe i missed that, i did have the id there before... Anyway that didn't solve the problem, now it doesn't click at all. I was trying to follow the answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595391/how-to-implement-pagination-on-a-custom-wp-query-ajax